# Stylized Google Maps Won't Show Up?

Tags: javascript, maps

I am new to this forum and currently having issue with this Stylized Google Maps. It's not showing up as it should be.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_OWN_KEY&sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

        // Create an array of styles.
        var styleArray = [
            {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [
                  { "saturation": -100 },
                  { "lightness": -32 }
                ]
            },{
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [
                  { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            },{
                "featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover",
                "stylers": [
                  { "saturation": -100 },
                  { "lightness": 63 }
                ]
            },{
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [
                  { "lightness": 4 },
                  { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }
        ]

        // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
        // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
        var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
            {name: "Styled Map"});

        // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
        // to the map type control.
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
            }
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            mapOptions);

        //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
        map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
        map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
    }
</script>
```

While the HTML is as below:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
```

Hopefully gurus here can help me with this. Thanks alot.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width to an actual `px`, and not a `%`, I'm not sure if you're using any sort of CSS with it, but setting to `100%` may conflict. e.g. Bootstrap.

Comment: Nope. No Bootstrap. It's my own CSS. I think it could be some mistake in Javascript. But I just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two bugs here.

You're not calling `initialize()` anywhere, so none of your JavaScript code runs. Add this line at the end of your script:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initialize );
```

After you fix that, load your page with the Developer Tools open and you'll see an error that `styles` is undefined, since you named the array `styleArray`. Change one or the other to match, and your map will load!

Comment: Thanks Mike for pointing these errors out :) It's finally working now.